# Get all list of Claims as a list them ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, identity

i created a list of both (1) Roles and (2) claims for ASP.NET core users in an Identity database.

I can retrieve all users using

```
  private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


    public IndexModel( DBContextClass context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    
    }
```

// and then in my code get all users using

```
var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
```

// and get all users in my table using

```
   Tbl_Brands_Staff = await _context.Tbl_Brands_Staff
            .Where(c => c.BrandID == id)
            .Where(a => a.IsEnabled)
            .ToListAsync();
```

// and in my view I use

```
<table class="table border-light" id="Agents">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].StaffID)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].UserName)
                                </th>

                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].First_Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].Last_Name)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].ContactNumber)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].DateCreated)
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tbl_Brands_Staff[0].IsEnabled)
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @foreach (var item in Model.Tbl_Brands_Staff)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffID)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactNumber)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsEnabled)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{if (item.IsEnabled)
                                            {
                                                <div id="_id">   <a class="btn btn-warning HGEnable" id="@item.StaffID" asp-page="./DisableEnable?id=@item.StaffID" asp-route-id="@item.BrandID">Enable</a></div>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            { <div id="_id">        <a class="btn btn-danger HGDisable" id="@item.StaffID" asp-page="./DisableEnable?id=@item.StaffID" asp-route-id="@item.BrandID">Disable</a></div>}
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

However how do I get/retrieve (or select ) all users claims from the ASPNetUserClaims (userId, ClaimType and ClaimValue) and list EVERYTHING  as in the images below ???

I tried, this (but unfortuantely it only gets the list of that one logged in user) I want all users with their respective claims and list them

```
 var p = User.Claims.Select(claim => new { claim.Type, claim.Value }).ToArray();
```

MY QUESTION IS SIMPLE. I want all users in the ASPNetUsersClaims table and their respective claims. Thank you

UPDATED CODE
I have added 2 images of a database claims from table ASPNetUserClaims and how I am trying to get it displayed in the browser. Does anyone know how it can be done ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9SFI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZIGF.png

thanks

Comment: Well, at the very end, you didn't make a question. But what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Claims are usually assigned to a user session when user logs in based on the role associated with the user. Then these claims are validated when the logged in user tries to access any resource in the application/api. You won't find them in the database because they are not stored in the database.

Comment: UPDATED CODE
I have added 2 images of a database claims from table ASPNetUserClaims and how I am trying to get it displayed in the browser. Does anyone know how it can be done ? thanks

Comment: Well, what stops you from fetching all this information from database tables directly? You could write your own simple helpers